# Attaching zip file is not working in WEB API, but works via POSTMAN

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, postman, zip

I have an .net core WEB API method that needs to call another external API (java) which expects .zip file. When try to access the external API via Postman by attaching the file, it is working fine (getting expected response). However when i pass the same parameters via my WEB API code, it is throwing 403-Forbidden error.

Please let me know if i am missing anything....

Thanks in advance!!!

[request-header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWLw9.png)

[request-body-file-attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY1r0.png)

[response-403-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtjzf.png)

API code: for connecting to api:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("pane", "forward");
parameters.Add("forward_path", "/store/execute");
parameters.Add("csrf", "1996fe6b2d0c97a8a0db725a10432d83");
parameters.Add("data_format", "binary");
newContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);


MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
HttpContent con;// = new StringContent("file_name");
//form.Add(con, "file_name");
form.Add(newContent);

var str = new FileStream("D:\\dummy\\xmlstore.zip", FileMode.Open);
con = new StreamContent(str);
con.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
    Name = "file_name",
    FileName = "xmlstore.zip"
};
con.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");

form.Add(con);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=05DEB277E294CBF73288F2E24682C7EE;");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("user-agent", "1"));
var resp = client.PostAsync("java-api", con).Result;
```

Comment: What authentication mode does the API expect?

Comment: hi tom, It expects a token which we are passing from API. its working for other APIs. but only for this it is throwing 403 error. i have attached the response error screenshot as well.

Comment: Where is the token in that code sample? I don't see a line that looks like adding a token, either as a query string parameter or as a header.

Comment: hi tom, we are passing csrf token as parameter and sessionid as cookie. i have included that part aswell in the code. we are passing these 2 things for all other APIs and it is working fine.